# malloc.c error when using a struct and multiple threads

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am getting an error which I have no idea how to fix. I am trying to work through the "producer-consumer" problem using  spin-lock. I created a "Queue"-like data structure as a shared resource to put "produced" items in, and to remove items to be "consumed". This is what my main program looks like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "Queue.h"

#define DEBUG 1

Queue_t* global_queue; // create a global queue

/* thread procedure for the producer thread */
void* producer_func(void* arg)
{
   while(1) // loops infinitely
   {
      int datum = rand() % global_queue->maximum_count;

      // spin while the queue is full
      while ((global_queue->current_count) ==
         (global_queue->maximum_count));

      enqueue(global_queue, datum);
      display(global_queue);
   }
}


/* thread procedure for the consumer thread */
void* consumer_func(void* arg)
{
   while(1) // loops infinitely
   {
      int datum = 0;

      // spin while there are no items in the queue
      while(global_queue->current_count == 0);

      datum = dequeue(global_queue);
      printf("The number consumed is %d\n");
   }
}


/* Main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   if(argc != 2)
   {
      printf("Error: wrong number of command-line arguments\n");
      printf("Usage: %s <integer>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
   }

   pthread_t producer;  // create producer thread
   pthread_t consumer;  // create consumer thread

   // create the queue object, get the max queue size
   //int max_count = atoi(argv[1]);
   global_queue = construct(10);
   display(global_queue);

   // intialize the random seed generator
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

   // create the threads and have them execute their routines
   pthread_create(&producer, NULL, &producer_func, NULL);
   pthread_create(&consumer, NULL, &consumer_func, NULL);

   // join the threads to finish
   pthread_join(producer, NULL);
   pthread_join(consumer, NULL);

   // deallocate the queue from memory
   //destruct(global_queue);

   return 0;
}
```

However, when I call the pthread_create in main routine, I get a bizarre error in malloc.c:

```
queue_demo: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Here is my "Queue" data structure header file:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

typedef struct Queue
{
   int  current_count;
   int  maximum_count;
   int  buffer[];       // queue uses an array
} Queue_t;


// routines to implement Queue-like functionality (FIFO)
// TODO: somehow encapsulate all these features in the struct itself.
//
Queue_t* construct(int buff_size);
void     destruct (Queue_t* queue);
void     display  (Queue_t* queue);
int      dequeue  (Queue_t* queue);
void     enqueue  (Queue_t* queue, const int datum);

#endif
```

And implementation:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Queue.h"

Queue_t* construct(int buff_size)
{
   Queue_t* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue_t));

   assert(queue != NULL);
   queue->maximum_count = buff_size;
   queue->current_count = 0;

   int i = 0;

   for(; i < queue->maximum_count; ++i)
      queue->buffer[i] = 0;

   return queue;
}

void destruct(Queue_t* queue)
{
   assert(queue != NULL);
   free(queue);
   printf("Queue destroyed!\n");
}

void display(Queue_t* queue)
{
   int i = 0;

   for(; i < queue->maximum_count; ++i)
      printf("%d ", queue->buffer[i]);
   printf("\n");
}

void enqueue(Queue_t* queue, const int datum)
{
   assert(queue->current_count < queue->maximum_count);
   queue->buffer[queue->current_count] = datum;
   ++queue->current_count;
}


int dequeue(Queue_t* queue)
{
   int i = 1;
   int datum = queue->buffer[0];

   assert(queue->current_count > 0);

   for(; i < queue->maximum_count; ++i)
   {
      queue->buffer[i-1] = queue->buffer[i];
      queue->buffer[i] = 0;
   }

   --queue->current_count;

   return datum;
}
```

Clearly, I am doing something very wrong. But I have no idea what exactly that is. I suspect it may have something to do with declaring the struct globally, but I am not sure. Any ideas  would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the homework tag is deprecated and has been removed from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `construct()` is not allocating space for the queue item data.

```
Queue_t* construct(int buff_size)
{
   Queue_t* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue_t));

   assert(queue != NULL);
   queue->maximum_count = buff_size;
   queue->current_count = 0;

   int i = 0;

   // HERE. Where is the item data space allocation ??
   for(; i < queue->maximum_count; ++i)
      queue->buffer[i] = 0;

   return queue;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
Queue_t* construct(int buff_size)
{
   // note space allocation for buffer[] bytes as well as overall structure.
   Queue_t* queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue_t) + sizeof(int) * buff_size);

   assert(queue != NULL);
   queue->maximum_count = buff_size;
   queue->current_count = 0;
   memset(queue->buffer, 0, sizeof(int)*buff_size);
   return queue;
}
```

I've not reviewed the rest of your code to determine if you're properly protecting concurrent access to the queue (that pthread mention makes me suspect you should be adding, and initializing, a pthread_mutex_t to the members of your Queue_t type, and using it for guarding concurrent queue modification). Regardless, the above is most-definitely a problem and should be taken care of *first*.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to make a difference. I should have added in the output that the test statement in main where i called `display(global_queue)` worked, as the output read all zeros in the array with the maximum size (in this case 10).

Comment: @Dylan if it worked without making the change I mentioned above, then either (a) the structure is not defined as you have shown here, or (b) completely undefined behavior. Your posted code *clearly* does not allocate space for the items **in** the queue, only the Queue_t members. This will *not* work as defined behavior. That said, I'll spend some time reviewing the rest of your code. Can you post a simplified `main()` at the bottom of your question above that demonstrates the problem, as well as the thread proc you're invoking? thanks.

Comment: @Dylan thanks for the updated post. As I suspected, your queue is exhibiting concurrency walk-over. You need a `pthread_mutex_t` to latch the queue during any access (push, pop, top, etc). Note that currently your producer can be shoving data into the queue and updating current_count *intertwined* with the consumer modifying (and relying on) the same members to pop data off. Do you understand, or would you like help adding this functionality?

Comment: I made test program for my `Queue_t` structure without threading and it worked consistently on my OS X machine. But I will note that my `destruct` routine *didn't* work, i.e. it throws a`free(): invalid next size` error. Also, the assignment we were given was to implement this first without using mutexes or semaphores, but just using a spin lock. Is this not possible using this kind of global structure?

Comment: @Dylan You can certainly do it with this. The spin-lock data, like the mutex, would be held in the `Queue_t` structure. Like the rest of the data in the queue object, it would be initialized at queue-creation, and destroyed at queue-destruction. Because you have a dedicated consumer and dedicated producer, a semaphore can work nicely as well, but ultimately you'll find using a mutex to be the easiest of these by *far* (imho).

Comment: @WhozCraig: it's homework.  Dylan: you didn't implement the spin lock.  See WhozCraig's comment.

Comment: @jdigital no worries. I think he has enough to go on, for sure. his text should have clear examples of spin-locks, mutexes, and semaphores, and how to integrate them reasonable. At least he isn't stomping all over undefined RAM now (still not sure how that worked to begin with, certainly undefined).

Comment: that was the example of the spin-lock I was given by my instructor (written in pseudo-code) for the produce and consume procedures. i see now that I have to actually use the `pthread_mutex` datatype to implement it. thank you.

Comment: @Dylan glad to help. you'll find a mutex very easy to integrate into this. (you should, anyway).